# python returns error regarding attributes when using stripped_strings while parsing a html content. This html content is added to the class

Tags: python

python returns error regarding attributes when using stripped_strings while parsing a html content. This html content is added to the class.
Here is the code snippet, the data that needs to be extracted is part of a list.

```
Updated Code :
```

from typing import List, Any, Optional

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class RESTApp:
    def **init**(self, url):
        self.url = url

```
def getAllUsers(self):
    # the list is added here
    data = '''<ul class="users-list clearfix">
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Alexander Pierce</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Today</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user8-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Norman</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">Yesterday</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user7-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Jane</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">12 Jan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user6-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">John</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">12 Jan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Alexander</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">13 Jan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user5-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Sarah</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">14 Jan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Nora</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">15 Jan</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <img src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="User Image">
                  <a class="users-list-name" href="#">Nadia</a>
                  <span class="users-list-date">15 Jan</span>
                </li>
              </ul>'''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    user_names = soup.find('ul', class_='users-list clearfix')
    split_details = list(user_names.stripped_strings)
    print(split_details)
    test = RESTApp("https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/profile.html")
    test.getAllUsers()
```

ACTUAL RESULT = AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stripped_strings'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing BeautifulSoup with a string literal, `'''data'''`, instead of the variable `data`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class RESTApp:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def getAllUsers(self):
        # the list is added here
        data = '''<ul class="users-list clearfix">
                <li>
                ...............
                </li>

                <li>
                ......
                </li>
                <li>
                .....
                </li>
            </ul>'''


        # parsing the data to get text from list.
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        user_names = soup.find('ul', class_='users-list clearfix')
        split_details = list(user_names.stripped_strings)
        print(split_details)

test = RESTApp("https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/profile.html")
test.getAllUsers()
```

Comment: Returns error for 

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: @Rima Did you copy my code or just update yours to not point to `'''data'''`? Your post had indentation errors I also fixed, but I didn't call them out because I wasn't sure that was your source code or just a copy/paste issue.

Comment: I am using PyCharm and fixed the indentation using Ctrl+Alt+I. So now there is no error but it returns nothing, Does not parse the data. What am I missing now?

Comment: @Rima I don't know. Using the code _exactly_ as I provided returns `['...............', '......', '.....']`. I'm not positive you've fixed all the indentation problems.

Comment: Updated the code snippet with the entire code that I am using.

Comment: @Rima Your updated code has formatting and indentation errors, so I'm not confident you've resolved it. When I copy your `data` into my code, it returns `['Alexander Pierce', 'Today', 'Norman', 'Yesterday', 'Jane', '12 Jan', 'John', '12 Jan', 'Alexander', '13 Jan', 'Sarah', '14 Jan', 'Nora', '15 Jan', 'Nadia', '15 Jan']` successfully. Make sure your `test = ...` assignment and call are not within the class definition. They need to be the same level of indentation as your `import` statements.

Comment: This is amazing.I am learning python, very new to this language and surprised how indentation changes the output. But worth all the hours spent on figuring out the problem. Thank you so very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Change `soup = BeautifulSoup('''data''', "html.parser")` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")`

Comment: Updated as you suggested and it returns 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: In such case, you have incorrect indentation for `data = ...` and `soup = ...` They must have the same level of indentation.

Comment: I am using PyCharm and fixed the indentation using Ctrl+Alt+I. So now there is no error but it returns nothing, Does not parse the data. What am I missing now?

Comment: Two last lines must be shifted one level to the left. Refer to the code @Web-Head has provided.

Comment: This is amazing.I am learning python, very new to this language and surprised how indentation changes the output. But worth all the hours spent on figuring out the problem. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: It would be more honest to mark @web-head's answer as accepted instead of mine as he provided the full code. :)